Is there a word for feeling both intense panic and peace at the same time?
I'm looking for a word which describes the feeling of peace and panic at the same time. I get this feeling a lot when I'm looking up a the stars, or when I'm underwater. I saw somebody call is 'vistoria', but I can't seem to find any other sources that agree with this. Is there even a word for a such a complicated feeling? I need it for the book I'm writing.
Used in a sentence, it would look like this: ''An intense feeling of (blank) washed over her''

Panic and peace are generally considered opposites of each other. Are you sure these are precisely what you mean? Can you provide more detail? You might feel sublimity looking up at the stars but I've no idea what you'd feel underwater (you mean while swimming, deep-sea diving, while drowning, ...?)

@StuartF I can imagine it the first time you scuba dive -- awe at the beauty but panic about potentially having an accident. Similarly for sky diving. But I can't think of a single word or phrase for this combination.

You might want to say  mixed emotions or, in some circumstances that you were conflicted but I don't think there is a single word that describes what you want.

"overwhelmed", "existential crisis", "insignificance", "dreadful peace" maybe?

Adrenaline rush.

What's wrong with: a simultaneous feeling of panic and peace

This is called the sublime.
The Oxford Dictionary of Philosophy gives the following definition of the sublime:

The sublime is great, fearful, noble, calculated to arouse sentiments of pride and majesty, as well as awe and sometimes terror.

The sublime then creates a strange mixture of feelings like pleasure, awe, anxiety, personal insignificance, and even fear and terror; think of one's mixed emotions, for example, when standing above a precipice gazing down on a majestic Norwegian fjord.
[World History Encyclopedia]

Awestruck, awe.

a feeling of reverential respect mixed with fear or wonder.


Welcome to our site! It looks like you've quoted a definition, but you haven't cited your source for it. Please edit your post to add your source – and ideally, if it's an online source, link it to the source page. For more guidance about how EL&U works, see [answer] and take the [Tour]. :-)
